# Bukkit - Low Velocity Snowballs

Tags: minecraft, bukkit, projectile

everyone. I'm having a little trouble with launching snowballs. I'm working on a plugin where, while a user is holding a snowball, they can sneak to charge a power bar. The player has a scoreboard in the side_bar that has a "power bar" that goes up and down from 1 to 10 while they are snaking. Once they right click to throw the snowball, it launches the ball at a velocity dependent on the users power level. A level of 5 is the default speed, a level of 10 is double the default speed, and a level of 1 is a fifth of the default speed, and the rest fill in that scale accordingly. I do this by multiplying the velocity by powerLevel/5.

This is all working splendidly. Well... kinda...

If the power level is 5 or above, it does what I expect it to do. However, if the power level is below 5 (slower than the default speed), the snowball just drops straight down. Is there a reason this happens? Can it be fixed? Any help on this would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is powerLevel an int?

Answer (score 0):

based on how much y velocity it has, the snowball will start to drop caused by gravity. to remove this, you would need to keep track of the snowball's y plane with the methods on this thread.
 [Calculate initial velocity to move a set distance with inertia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487065/calculate-initial-velocity-to-move-a-set-distance-with-inertia)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that a fifth of the snowball's velocity is about dropping when you throw it.  In order to fix it; you'll need to set the Y level higher so it doesn't fall.